# Upload a Folder to S3 bucket in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I upload an entire folder to the S3 Bucket or all the files of my folder to s3 bucket folder.

Right now I am only able to upload a file using the following code :
I want to upload a folder having  .gif,.jpeg,.html etc kind of files in it .

```
  def myfunction(location,source_file)
            s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'region-name')
            obj = s3.bucket(bucket-name).object(location)
            obj.upload_file(source_file)
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Amazon S3 API call to upload multiple files. You will need to **upload one at a time**, but you can do them in parallel if your programming language does multi-threading.

If you just need to copy files rather than including this functionality within your own app, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It provides a `aws s3 cp --recursive` command and a `aws s3 sync` command that can copy whole directories for you. (It recursively copies each file.)